# Wait until previous query is complete before running the next one

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

The code below forms part of a websocket that connects to a third party API and receives messages quite frequently from it, currently there are about 3 messages that all appear in very quick succession and I was wondering how I could make sequelize wait until executing one query before the next

```
this.client.ws.on(WebSocketEvent.ON_MESSAGE, async (message) => {
    if (message.type == 'received') {
        await db.Order.create({
            symbol: message.product_id,
            orderId: message.order_id,
            price: message.funds,
            side: message.side,
            orderedAt: message.time,
            sold: false
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            process.exit();
        });
    } else if (message.type == 'match') {
        await db.Order.update({
            volume: message.size
        }, {
            where: {
                orderId: message.taker_order_id
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    } else if (message.type == 'done') {
        console.log(message);
        await db.Order.update({
            completeAt: message.time
        }, {
            where: {
                orderId: message.order_id
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
```

Basically what should happen is a message should come through with the type `received` and that creates a row in the `Order` table, a split second later a match message should come through and theoretically it should wait for the previous query to run before updating the previously created order, although this is not the case and the model is not updated.

I've thought about simply adding a delay to the code blocks below the `match` and `done` message types but would there be any other way to implement what I am looking for?